# Apache Spark Shell is not able to start Executor, getting EXITED in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to launch Spark-Shell  over cluster and getting the error as follows-

```
16/07/21 11:27:28 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160721112151-0000/179 is now RUNNING
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160721112151-0000/177 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160721112151-0000/177 removed: Command exited with code 1
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 177
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160721112151-0000/180 on worker-20160721112059-10.65.104.9-43892 (10.65.104.9:43892) with 8 cores
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160721112151-0000/180 on hostPort 10.65.104.9:43892 with 8 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
16/07/21 11:27:33 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160721112151-0000/180 is now RUNNING
16/07/21 11:27:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160721112151-0000/178 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
16/07/21 11:27:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160721112151-0000/178 removed: Command exited with code 1
16/07/21 11:27:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 178
16/07/21 11:27:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160721112151-0000/181 on worker-201607211

12059-10.65.105.6-37622 (10.65.105.6:37622) with 8 cores
```

I tried submitting job as well and the result remains same.
I have checked my slaves file and checked all config but couldn't find anything wrong.

Same thing is not happening when trying to launch shell as local, so I think it can be related to hosts so I checked /etc/host -

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       theubuntu
10.65.104.9     Mainserver
10.65.105.6     Client1
10.65.104.16    Client2
10.65.104.14    Client3
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Look at the logs in your spark worker, there's a problem with the executor process.

Comment: yup that worked now

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my Spark-env.sh, I have provided

```
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411
```

but that port was not available and Worker logs inside SPark_Home\work\Application_Id , logged the error precisely which I didn't see.